# A question about the probability of obtaining ∣y+⟩ given the initial state ∣$\psi$⟩ in a spin 1/2 system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

> Suppose that a spin 1/2 particle is prepared in a state with probability 3/4 of being in the state ∣z+⟩ and 1/4 of being in the state ∣y+⟩. What is the probability of getting ∣y+⟩ after a measurement of the spin in the y direction?

According to the problem, the initial state ∣$\psi$⟩ of the particle is

∣$\psi$⟩=$\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{4}}$∣z+⟩ + $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}}$ ∣y+⟩ $\quad \quad$(1)

Knowing that ∣z+⟩= $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$∣y+⟩+$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$∣y−⟩ and putting that in (1) we get

∣$\psi$⟩=$\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{4}} + \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}}\Bigg)∣y+⟩ + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{4}} ∣y−⟩ $

But $\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{4}} + \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}}\Bigg)^2>1$, which gives a probability greater than 1 for getting ∣y+⟩.

Where am I wrong in the above reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the question, as the wavefunction is not properly normalized from the start.

Whoever wrote this problem seems to think that as long as the sum of the squares of the coefficients is one, the wavefunction is normalized. But this is only true if all the components are normalized and orthogonal to one another. $\def\ket#1{\left|#1\right>}\ket{z+}$ and $\ket{y+}$ are not orthogonal, so the original wavefunction is not normalized, despite looking like it is at first glance.

Specifically, $$\def\bracket#1#2{\left<#1\middle|#2\right>}\bracket\psi\psi=\frac34\bracket{z+}{z+}+\frac14\bracket{y+}{y+}+\frac{\sqrt3}4\left(\bracket{z+}{y+}+\bracket{y+}{z+}\right)=\frac{4+\sqrt{6}}{4}>1$$

As usual, you can normalize $\ket\psi$ by dividing by $\sqrt{\bracket\psi\psi}$.

Comment: In this case, is there a way to normalize ∣$\psi$⟩ maintaining the initial given probabilities?

Comment: @Slayer: with the information given you can infer that $\vert\psi\rangle= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\vert +z\rangle + \frac{e^{i\phi}}{2}\vert -z\rangle$ so there remains to find the phase $e^{i\phi}$ that will get you the right probability for measuring $\vert +y\rangle$.  (This problem, if it has a solution, is quite cute for the reason mentioned by Chris.)